# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: setPageProvider <- setPage

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am trying to create a pagination for my page using angularjs framework. Currently, I am getting the error that `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: setPageProvider <- setPage`. I tried changing the arrangement of the code but it still the same. I tried to follow the tutorial from [this website](http://www.angularcode.com/angularjs-datagrid-paging-sorting-filter-using-php-and-mysql/) but its not working. Can i know the way to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

This is my controller.js code:

```
(function () {

angular.module('myApp', ['MovieApp']).
    filter('startFrom', function() {
        return function(input, start) {
            if(input) {
                start = +start; //parse to int
                return input.slice(start);
            }
            return [];
        }
    }
    );

"use strict";
angular.module('MovieApp').
    controller('SearchController', 
            [  
                '$scope', 
                'dataService', 
                '$location',
                '$routeParams',
                '$timeout',
                'setPage',
                '$filter',

                function ($scope, dataService, $location, $routeParams, $timeout, $setPage, $filter){
                    $scope.searchMovies = [ ];
                    $scope.searchCount = 0;

                    var getSearchResult = function () {
                        dataService.getSearchResult().then(
                            function (response) {
                                $scope.searchCount = response.rowCount + ' movies';
                                $scope.searchMovies = response.data;
                                $scope.showSuccessMessage = true;
                                $scope.successMessage = "All movie Success";

                                $scope.currentPage = 1; //current page
                                $scope.entryLimit = 5; //max no of items to display in a page
                                $scope.filteredItems = $scope.searchMovies.length; //Initially for no filter
                                $scope.totalItems = $scope.searchMovies.length;
                            },
                            function (err){
                                $scope.status = 'Unable to load data ' + err;
                            }
                        );  // end of getStudents().then
                    };

                    $scope.setPage = function(pageNo) {
                        $scope.currentPage = pageNo;
                    };

                    $scope.filter = function() {
                        $timeout(function() {
                            $scope.filteredItems = $scope.filtered.length;
                        }, 10);
                    };

                    getSearchResult();

                }
            ]
        );

 }());
```

This is my search.html code:

```
<div>

<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchMovie" ng-change="filter()"></label><br><br><br><br>
</div>
<div ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
    <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
        <thead>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="searchmovie in filtered = (searchMovies | filter:searchMovie) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">

            </tr>   
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div ng-show="filteredItems > 0">
    <div pagination="" page="currentPage" on-select-page="setPage(page)" 
    boundary-links="true" total-items="filteredItems" items-per-page="entryLimit" 
    previous-text="&laquo;" next-text="&raquo;">
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add the pagination for the page so that i can see the result in the table as in a page.

Comment: Have you injected the 'setPage' service ?

Comment: I am sorry @JyotiPrakash what do you mean by injecting setpage? I am new to angularjs framework

Comment: angular.module('appName', ['setPage']);

Comment: you have to register the 'setPage' service to your application like above

Comment: @JyotiPrakash where should i do that? I did in the filter module but its not working

Comment: just do this any where in you app :  
angular.module('myApp', ['setPage']);

Comment: are there any sample of it? because i tried adding the code inside my MovieApp but now its showing more errors on my console

Answer (score 0):

You're injecting `setPage` in your `SearchController`, but the service/factory doesn't exist.

Comment: can i know how can i solve it? I am new to angularjs framework. I am following the tutorial from the website link which is posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller `'SearchController'` you are injecting `'setPage'` and `$setPage`. Remove both injections.

**EDIT:**

```
angular.module('MovieApp')
    .controller('SearchController', 
        ['$scope', 'dataService', '$location', '$routeParams', '$timeout', '$filter'
        , function ($scope, dataService, $location, $routeParams, $timeout, $filter){
            // Some code..
    }]);
```

Comment: actually now i am getting a new error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: startFromFilterProvider <- startFromFilter`

Comment: Did you include your `controller.js` in your layout template?

Comment: yes i have done that..btw the other controllers are working actually only the pagination search controller not working

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by myself. I had to reedit the module code in my controller.js file. This is the solution for it

```
var app = angular.module('MovieApp');
    app.filter('startFrom', function() {
        return function(input, start) {
            if(input) {
                start = +start; //parse to int
                return input.slice(start);
            }
            return [];
        }
    });
```